# "General error: 1 foreign key mismatch" on "dropColumn" in Laravel

Tags: laravel, sqlite, migration, database-migration

Firstly, I'm using **SQLite**, and have `foreign_key_constraints = TRUE` in my `config->database->sqlite` file.

I've got 4 tables which are all created with my Laravel migrations.

- users
- events
- event_user
- event_logs

**create_users_table**

```
$table->uuid('id')->unique();
$table->string('name');
$table->string('email')->unique();
$table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
$table->string('password');
$table->rememberToken();
$table->timestamps();
```

**create_events_table**

```
$table->uuid('id')->unique();
$table->string('name');
$table->dateTimeTz('startDateTime');
$table->dateTimeTz('endDateTime');
$table->integer('min_participants')->nullable();
$table->integer('max_participants')->nullable();
$table->timestamps();
```

**create_event_user_table**

```
$table->uuid('event_id');
$table->uuid('user_id');
$table->timestamps();

$table->foreign('event_id')
    ->references('id')->on('events')
    ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

**create_event_logs_table**

```
$table->uuid('id')->unique();
$table->dateTimeTz('dateTime');
$table->uuid('user_id');
$table->uuid('event_id');
$table->float('value', 12, 2);
$table->timestamps();

$table->foreign('event_id')
    ->references('id')->on('events')
    ->onDelete('cascade');

$table->foreign('user_id')
    ->references('id')->on('users')
    ->onDelete('cascade');
```

They all work fine, but when I alter the `users` table, I get a `General error: 1 foreign key mismatch - "event_logs" referencing "users"` error.

**update_users_table**

```
$table->string('family_name')->nullable()->after('name');
$table->string('given_name')->nullable()->after('name');

$table->dropColumn('name');
```

If I comment out the `$table->dropColumn('name')` then the migrations work fine.

Full error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 foreign key mismatch - "event_logs" referencing "users" (SQL: INSERT INTO users (id, email, email_verified_at, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at) SELECT id, email, email_verified_at, password, remember_token, created_at, updated_at FROM __temp__users)
```

Comment: Does this `dropColumn()` follow the full 12 step process listed in https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html ?

Comment: That error message strongly suggests it's following the work flow explicitly marked as incorrect in the documentation.